# Equivalent norms in $C^1([0,1], \mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to prove that in $C^1([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ the norms

$$||f||_1 = |f(0)|+\max_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)| \ \text{and} \ ||f||_2 = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| + \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)|$$ are equivalent.

What I did:
$$\begin{align*}
||f||_1 &= |f(0)|+\max_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)| \\
& \leq \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| + \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)|\\
& \leq 1\cdot ||f||_2
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
 ||f||_1 &= |f(0)|+\max_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)| \\
 & = |f(x)-\int_{a}^x f'(x)| + \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)|, \ a \in [0,1] \\
& = |f(x)-f'(x)|+\max_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)| \\
& \geq ||f(x)|-|f'(x)|| + \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)|
\end{align*}
$$
and I got stuck here. Any tip?

Comment: We have $$ \vert f(x)\vert \leq \vert f(x)-f(0)\vert +\vert f(0)\vert \leq (\sup_{y\in [0,x]} \vert f'(y)\vert) \vert x\vert + \vert f(0)\vert \leq \Vert f\Vert_1.$$ Taking sup over $x$ yields $$\sup_{x\in [0,1]} \vert f(x)\vert \leq \Vert f \Vert_1.$$ Thus, we get $\Vert f\Vert_2\leq 2 \Vert f \Vert_1.$

Comment: Nice answer @SeverinSchraven, thanks, I was trying to use that f(x) = f(a) + int_a^x f'(t) dt, but this way is actually much simpler

Comment: I am kind of using that with $a=0$ :) you were on the right track.

Comment: Also, note that the inequality I derived is sharp. Namely, $\Vert x \Vert_2=2\Vert x\Vert_1$. Thus, we cannot get a better constant.

Comment: I suggest you write up the details as an answer in order to get your question off the unanswered list.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I realized where you're using the inequality. I'm just not understanding  why do you say that (sup |f'(y)|)x + |f(0)| <= ||f||_1. Thank you very much

Comment: Because $0\leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: How do I do to get the question off the unanswered list? :) @SeverinSchraven

Comment: You can write up an answer in the field below and accept it. This way you can also check whether you understood everything and people can upvote it (this will give you some nice perks once you have a couple of upvotes).

Answer (score 0):

On one hand, one has that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
     \lVert f  \rVert_1 &= |f(0)| + \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)| \\
    & \leq \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| + \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)|\\
    & \leq 1\cdot  \lVert f  \rVert_2
\end{split}
\end{equation}

On the other hand, we have that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    |f(x)| &\leq |f(x)-f(0)|+|f(0)| \\
    &\leq \left \lvert \int_0^x f'(t) \, dt \right \rvert + |f(0)| \\
    & \leq (x-0)\sup_{y\in [0,x]} |f'(y)| + |f(0)| \\
    & \leq \left \lVert f \right \rVert_1
\end{split}
\end{equation}

and taking the supremum on both sides from we have
\begin{equation*}
    \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| \leq \left \lVert f \right \rVert_1
\end{equation*}
which implies that $\left \lVert f \right \rVert_2 \leq 2 \cdot \left \lVert f \right \rVert_1$, which proves that these norms are equivalent.